# blood contamination rna seq

Tags: rna-seq

I have tumor rna seq samples. I want to find out percentage of blood contamination within these samples. What is the best possible way to find % of blood contamination within the rna seq samples?

Answer (score 5):

I assume by "blood contamination" you are interested in tumor purity and immune cell infiltration. For that you can use a deconvolution tool for bulk RNA-seq like [CIBERSORT](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5895181/) or [quanTIseq](https://icbi.i-med.ac.at/software/quantiseq/doc/)